# DispatchGroup notify method should only run once after all events are finished in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

I have the code below that I use using a "DispatchGroup":

```
// class variables
let myUploadGroup = DispatchGroup()
var concatenatedUploadGroupMessage:String = ""

// inside a method I have the code below
for resFoto in resFotosResenhaEscolhidas {
        
        myUploadGroup.enter()
        
        jsonRequestUploadImagem = ResFotosModel.createJsonFotoResenha(resFoto, resenhaDados.IdGedave)
                    
        let requestUploadImagem: NSMutableURLRequest = serviceRepository.clientURLRequest(wsUploadImagem, typeAutho: .basic, parms: "", body: jsonRequestUploadImagem as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
        
        serviceRepository.post(requestUploadImagem, retryLogin: true, completion: {isOk,msgError,httpCode,needLogin,response in
            self.checkResponseUploadImagemFotoResenha(response as AnyObject, httpCode)
        })
        
    }

func checkResponseUploadImagemFotoResenha(_ response:AnyObject, _ httpCode:Int) {
    
    if httpCode != 200 {
        let string = String(data: response as! Data, encoding: .utf8)
        print( string!+" \n Erro HTTP: "+String(httpCode) )
        myUploadGroup.leave()
        AlertActions.showBasicAlert(erroParaExibir: string!+" \n Erro HTTP: "+String(httpCode), currentView: self)
    } else {
        // httpCode == 200
        let data: Data = response as! Data // received from a network request, for example
        
        let jsonResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        
        guard let dictionary = jsonResponse as? [String: Any] else { return }
        guard let nestedDictionary = dictionary["RetornoGravacaoImagemWSVO"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
        
        let mensagem = nestedDictionary["mensagem"] as! String
        let codigo = nestedDictionary["codigo"] as! Int
        
        
        if codigo != 200 {
            print("Erro upload foto - codigo: \(codigo)")
            concatenatedUploadGroupMessage = concatenatedUploadGroupMessage+" \(mensagem) - \(codigo) \n"
        } else {
            let nomeArquivo = nestedDictionary["nomeArquivo"] as! String
            concatenatedUploadGroupMessage = concatenatedUploadGroupMessage+" \(nomeArquivo) - \(mensagem) \n"
        }
        
        
        myUploadGroup.leave()
    }
    
    myUploadGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        AlertActions.showBasicAlert(erroParaExibir: self.concatenatedUploadGroupMessage, currentView: self)
        print("Finished all requests.")
        CustomLoadingBar.hide(self) // use in conjunction with the Grand Dispatcher Group
    }
    
    
}
```

I use "myUploadGroup.enter()" and "myUploadGroup.leave()" to send the signal to start and end the request.

After that I have the method "myUploadGroup.notify".

When all request are made, for example, 4 http requests are started and when they finish I can see the message "Finished all requests." print 4 times in the console.

What I want to do is when the 4 http requests are finished, I only want to see the message message "Finished all requests." printed once on the console instead of seeing the message printed 4 times.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `myUploadGroup.notify()` in your function `checkResponseUploadImagemFotoResenha()`, which is called from your completion handler. That means you are calling `myUploadGroup.notify()` more than once. Don't do that.

Rewrite your code that queues up your requests like this:

```
for requestInfo in requests {
    myUploadGroup.enter()
    submitRequest( completion: {
       // Process response
       myUploadGroup.leave()
}

myUploadGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
   // Code to execute once when all the requests have completed
}
```

Note how I put the call to notify after the loop that submits the requests.

Answer (score 0):

I was able find a solution to my problem without the need to rewrite my code to queue up my requests.

I create a class variable

```
var counter:Int = 0
```

Before my "myUploadGroup.enter()" function I add the following code

```
counter = counter + 1
```

In my "myUploadGroup.notify" function I add this code

```
self.counter = self.counter - 1
if self.counter == 0 {
   print("I run once")
}
```

It works for me now.